# Is converting cookie auth session to token safe?

Tags: jwt, xss, csrf

I want to create a http service handler which converts an existing auth session cookie into a token (i.e., JSON Web Token). Should I be concerned with XSS or any other vulnerability, or am I simply covered by modern browsers disabling CORS by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is hard to tell without more info on the use case: it depends on what information will be included in the JSON web token, to what clients it will be sent (e.g. in different domains and/or controlled by different entities), how these clients will use it (e.g. over https or not), and what the clients use if for (e.g. would it act as the user or under a restricted set of permissions)

also note that standard OAuth 2.0 allows for this scenario already: you can leverage an existing web session (ie. in a `code` flow) to authenticate against the Authorization Server and send tokens down to OAuth 2.0 clients; a correct implementation of the OAuth 2.0 spec would warrant against the said vulnerabilities

Comment: Thanks Hans. That's a good point you make about OAuth. It does sound like a similar workflow. One difference is that usually the OAuth provider asks the user for the first time if they want to allow requestor example.com to have OAuth access, and the user has to consent. In my case, my software does not ask the user, but on the other hand my server has a restricted access-control-allow-origin list. I intend to use it for different subdomains of my site, as well as a mobile app, always on https and in my software. I'd like to use scopes to reduce risk.

Comment: Another difference I think is that OAuth redirects the caller to the requesting url (which is authorized either by asking user, or by pre-registration, or both) with the token in the url, whereas I would like my http request handler to return the token directly in the http response body.

Comment: a) OAuth 2.0 also allows for scenario's where no explicit consent is required and "pre-authorization" is arranged through whitelisting; b) there is a POST binding for OAuth 2.0 as well, see http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html

Comment: Thanks Hans. It sounds to me then that it's ok, assuming proper access-control-allow-origin, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: well, the OAuth 2.0 flow is handled through the (full) browser and not in Ajax calls so CORS does not apply to the mechanism of **issuing/obtaining** an access token and thus to the "conversion" from cookie to token; it may apply if you want to **use** it in an Ajax call against an API in a different domain than the one you received it on, but that is beyond OAuth 2.0

Comment: In my scenario, a user could have a session cookie in the browser, and I just want to make sure there is no XSS exploit to obtain the token at the conversion url. That's what it seems CORS restriction would prevent.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your service handler only takes the session cookie value as input and then outputs it as JSON?

In that case, as long as you use a standard, tried and tested JSON encoder then you will be safe against [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29). [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) should not be an issue as your method is a [safe method](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) and the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will prevent your cookie being read by another domain as you are not opting into CORS.